# Xcode UITesting - how to move UISlider?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-ui-testing

Is there a way to move `UISlider` under `UITests` target in Xcode? I really need to move it from code. Is it possible?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. Get your slider:

   ```
   let app = XCUIApplication()
   let timeSlider = app.sliders["timeSlider"]
   ```
2. Adjust its value:

   ```
   timeSlider.adjustToNormalizedSliderPosition(0.9)
   ```

Answer (score 3):

I made this extension based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34165425/1082430) answer to fix the `adjustToNormalizedSliderPosition` problem.

```
import XCTest

extension XCUIElement {

    open func adjust(toNormalizedSliderValue normalizedSliderValue: CGFloat) {
        let start = coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: 0.0))
        let end = coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: normalizedSliderValue, dy: 0.0))
        start.press(forDuration: 0.05, thenDragTo: end)
    }

}
```

Then you only have to call instead:

```
app.sliders["Your Slider Identifier"].adjust(toNormalizedSliderValue: 0.5)
```

Here you can find some other useful tips for Xcode UITesting:

https://github.com/joemasilotti/UI-Testing-Cheat-Sheet

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.2+**

[@bartłomiej-semańczyk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35298469/3127015) answer, modified a little bit like this:

1. Get your slider:

```swift
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    let timeSlider = app.sliders["timeSlider"]
```

2. Adjust its value:

```swift
    timeSlider.adjust(toNormalizedSliderPosition: 0.9)
```

**Note:** The number is `CGFloat` and it is between 0 and 1.
If your UISlider minimum and maximum value is not 0 to 1 you have to convert it first like this:

```swift
    let numberBetween01 = CGFloat((requestedVal - UISlider.minimumValue ) / UISlider.maximumValue - UISlider.minimumValue))
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get `adjustToNormalizedSliderPosition` to work with my app's slider. I've seen some people posting online that it also didn't work for them. 
Is it working for others here?

A less useful method to adjust a slider is to find the element, press for a duration, then drag to another element:

```
slider.pressForDuration(duration: 0.05, thenDragToElement: anotherElement)
```

Comment: Hm. I verified that I did in fact have an accessibilityIdentifier set for the slider, but was still unable to adjust the slider using your posted solution. Any other ideas of what could be going wrong for me? I'm able to successfully locate the element by accessibilityIdentifier and perform other actions on it, just not `adjustToNormalizedSliderPosition`.

Answer (score 0):

**How to move UISlider to Right ➡️**

```
  static func moveSliderToRight(element: XCUIElement){
  _ =  element.waitForExistence(timeout: 10)
    element.adjust(toNormalizedSliderPosition: 1)
}
```

**How to move UISlider to Left ⬅️**

```
  static func moveSliderToRight(element: XCUIElement){
  _ =  element.waitForExistence(timeout: 10)
    element.adjust(toNormalizedSliderPosition: 0)
}
```